# Notepad++ cannot open deep nested files from the FTP

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I am using nppFTP to connect to my development server. I can only open files that are 3-4 levels deep. It may be because the base directory name is really long (something like e778de749db7d41c5666a8ee2895475ea), and the complete path name is too long for Notepad++ to handle.

I can pull from git without a problem, FTP clients like FileZilla can also open the files.

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Since you are using Git already, are you open to change your current deployment setup for a rather smarter one through Git?

Comment: Sure, I love and use git all the time. However there are use cases where I must use FTP on Nodepad++. I have come across this 'bug' several times. It always happens when the file in question is too deep nested.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback on the comments section, I would suggest you switch to a Git FTP deployment workflow. I use such a workflow myself and I love it.

To achiave it, you have to use one of several tools that exists for this, to name a few:

- [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) (bash)
- [git-ftp](https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp) (python)
- [PHPloy](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy) (php)

All those allow you to configure your FTP details and deploy based on git version comparison. Pick the one you like.

Disclaimer: I've build PHPloy.

Comment: I work locally on WAMP and my git serevr is in the cloud. Does PHPloy work in this case?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's designed to be a local tool. It does not matter if you have a remote repo or not.